# $\{U_i, i\in I\}$ is an open cover of $X$, show that $\dim{X}=\sup{\{\dim U_i, i\in I\}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

The problem is from Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry. $X$ is a topological space. If $\{U_i, i\in I\}$ is an open cover of $X$ then $\dim{X}=\sup{\{\dim U_i, i\in I\}}$.

It is easy to show that $\dim{X}\geq\sup{\{\dim U_i, i\in I\}}$. To prove "$\leq$":

Suppose there exists a chain of irreducible closed subsets of $X$:

$$Y_0\subsetneq Y_1 \subsetneq ... \subsetneq Y_n \subset X$$

If we can show that

$$(Y_0\cap U_i) \subsetneq (Y_1\cap U_i) \subsetneq ... \subsetneq (Y_n\cap U_i) \subset U_i$$

is a chain of irreducible closed sets of $U_i$ for some $i$, then we are done.

This is where troubles me. I cannot show that $(Y_j\cap U_i) \subsetneq (Y_{j+1}\cap U_i)$. I can find a $U_i$ for each pair of $Y_j$ and $Y_{j+1}$, since if $y\in Y_{j+1}$ but $y\notin Y_j$, we can always find a $U_i$ such that $y\in U_i$, then $(Y_j\cap U_i) \subsetneq (Y_{j+1}\cap U_i)$ for this particular $j$ and $i$. But how to show that this $U_i$ works for the whole chain?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This is ex 1.10 from Algebraic Geometry by Hartshorne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not use that the $Y_j$ are irreducible.

Take $i$ such that $Y_0 \cap U_i \neq \emptyset$. We obtain $Y_j \cap U_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $j$.

$Y_j \cap U_i$ is dense in $Y_j$, since $Y_j$ is irreducible. $Y_{j-1} \cap U_i$ is contained in the closed subset $Y_{j-1}$ of $Y_j$. This shows that $Y_{j-1} \cap U_i$ is not dense in $Y_j$, hence cannot be all of the dense open $Y_j \cap U_i$.